# How to fill an SVG path with circles?

Tags: javascript, svg

I have a path (green in the image below), and I need to fill it with a dynamic number of circles.

For example I know from the start that the most circles a path can contain is 500, and as a JS script runs in a browser, I will need to display 300 circles inside the path. It doesn't matter how the circles are arranged, just that they are inside the path. How do I calculate the positions inside the path with a little bit of padding between each circle?

I've been thinking of `getBBox` of the path, generating a grid inside it, then checking each X,Y position with `isPointInFill`, but this only checks the center of the circle and ones on the edge will overflow the path.

Is there any library that can do the heavy lifting for this situation? Or otherwise how would you accomplish this?

[image]

Comment: If you combine `isPointInFill` with measuring the distance of a point from the path, you should be able to make decisions. Finding the distance is relatively elementary: iterate along the path with `getPointAtLength` and compute the distance for each of them. There is also a small (just 40 lines) [library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/distance-from-path) available.

Comment: Please show us a code example of your current svg. You can also expand the detection area by applying a `stroke-width` (1 or 1.5 x grid cell width) and check both  `isPointInFill()`  and `isPointInStroke()`.